# NIfi: How to ingest a big table

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to ingest a really big table in nifi using QueryDatabaseTable or ExecuteSQL. It doesn't seem to work.. The same query works for smaller tables.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Getting a numeric overflow with GenerateTableFetch

```
 GenerateTableFetch GenerateTableFetch[id=245bd83a-0157-1000-73ab-275171c79348] 
Unable to execute SQL select query 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CATALOG_SALES due to java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
```

Answer (score 4):

What kind of error are you getting? You may be running into the following:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1251

If you are using NiFi 1.0 you can use the [GenerateTableFetch](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch/index.html) processor. It allows you to choose the "page" (aka partition) size, and will generate SQL statements, each of which will grab one "page" of data. You can route those into ExecuteSQL and it will retrieve smaller sets of results at a time. If you have a NiFi cluster, you can route GenerateTableFetch into a [Remote Process Group](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#configure-site-to-site-client-nifi-instance) that points at an [Input Port](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#input_port) on the same cluster, (which will distribute the SQL statements across the cluster), then the Input Port can be connected to the ExecuteSQL. This allows you to fetch rows from a table in parallel.